# Regex Output Count

Tags: python-3.x, counter

I am trying to count the output of a regex search I am conducting on a dataset but for some reason my count is off by a lot. I was wondering what I am doing wrong and how I can get an official count. I should have around 1500 matches but I keep getting an error that says "'int' object is not iterable".

```
import re

with open ('Question 1 Logfile.txt' , 'r') as h:
    results = []
    count = []
    for line in h.readlines():
        m = re.search(r'(((May|Apr)(\s*)\w+\s\w{2}:\w{2}:\w{2}))', line)
        t = re.search(r'(((invalid)(\s(user)\s\w+)))',line)
        i = re.search(r'(((from)(\s\w+.\w+.\w+.\w+)))', line)
        if m and t and i:
            count += 1
            print(m.group(1),' - ',i.group(4),' , ',t.group(4))
            print(count)
```

Comment: here count is a list during the initialization and you can't increment a list object.Make count =0

Comment: @bigbounty Yes, Thank you I cant believe I missed that. One last quick question, this method is counting each output as they come, how can I make one total count at the end?

Comment: @bigbounty how do I upvote a comment? and can you explain what you mean by saying count.append(1)?

Comment: Get your cursor to the top left side bar of my comment.You will see a upward facing arrow.Click on that. What I meant by that was, instead of incrementing count everytime,you store if the condition is true by count.append(1) or count.append(0).So,finally when you sum the count list,the value will be same as incrementing count each time.

Comment: @bigbounty I dont think count.append is a thing,I am getting an error that say 'int object has not attribute append'

Comment: If you want to use append,then make count as a list.Use count=[]

Comment: I think you better study python than asking these questions

Comment: @bigbounty I am studying python...that is why I am asking questions... thank you for the help I hope you have a good day.

Comment: Oh..Ok .No problem.Happpy Learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to increment the number of times you satisfy a condition over a series of loop iterations.  The confusion here seems to be how exactly to do that, and what variable to increment.

Here's a small example that captures the difficulty you've encountered, as described in OP and in OP comments.  It's meant as a learning example, but it does also provide a couple of options for a solution.

```
count = []
count_int = 0

for _ in range(2):
    try:
        count += 1
    except TypeError as e:
        print("Here's the problem with trying to increment a list with an integer")
        print(str(e))

    print("We can, however, increment a list with additional lists:")
    count += [1]
    print("Count list: {}\n".format(count))

    print("Most common solution: increment int count by 1 per loop iteration:")
    count_int +=1
    print("count_int: {}\n\n".format(count_int))

print("It's also possible to check the length of a list you incremented by one element per loop iteration:")
print(len(count))
```

Output:

```
"""
Here's the problem with trying to increment a list with an integer: 
'int' object is not iterable

We can, however, increment a list with additional lists:
Count list: [1]

Most common is to increment an integer count by 1, for each loop iteration:
count_int: 1


Here's the problem with trying to increment a list with an integer: 
'int' object is not iterable

We can, however, increment a list with additional lists:
Count list: [1, 1]

Most common is to increment an integer count by 1, for each loop iteration:
count_int: 2


It's also possible to check the length of a list you incremented 
by one element per loop iteration: 
2
"""
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck learning Python!